# Custom Command Passing Converstation Text

Tags: c#, lync

Does anyone know if it is possible for a custom Lync command to pass the conversation text in as an argument? I know I can pass in the %user-id% and %contact-id% but as far as I know those are the only arguments that I can pass.  Ultimately what I am looking to do is have a C# console application that gets executed via a lync custom command.  The console app then would take the conversation, user id and contact id and log it to a database. Is this even possible?  Are there any other ways that this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to the Lync client automation from your console client. Since you know all parties involved in the conversation, it should be possible to enumerate the active conversations and find the one which send the command.